# How do I avoid a pinch puncture?

Tags: tire

Newly mended inner tube went down within 15 minutes of pumping up and without any riding or even sitting on bike. Handpump only so no idea of pressure. What did I do wrong/ how can I avoid it happening again?

Comment: Obviously, you didn't fix the hole.  Either that or you somehow poked a new hole while installing the tire.  (Very rarely you can see this due to an over-long spoke poking through it's nipple.)

Comment: This is correct- I only mended one puncture of the snake bite as I didnt see the other when the bigger one was leaking. Sorry to bother you. I presume it was done with my tyre levers (old spoons).

Comment: "Snake bite" is what it's called when a single incident causes two holes.  Occasionally the cause is something like a long nail, but usually the cause is hitting a curb or other major bump when tire pressure is too low.

Comment: And don't use old metal tire spoons (and especially not screwdrivers), except in emergency.  Use plastic tire levers, or, better still, a single plastic "[quick stick](https://www.perennialcycle.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/Q/u/Quik_Stik_Quik_Stik_Tire_Lever.jpg)".

Answer (score 5):

Most likely:

1. You didn't repair the original puncture properly, and air was still leaking from that site.
2. Whatever caused the puncture in the first place is still in the tire, and re-punctured the tube.
3. There was more than one puncture, possibly a small one that you didn't notice when finding the major one.

Possibly you also nicked the tube with a tire lever when getting the tire off. I think this might be what you are alluding to in your title.

By the way a 'pinch' puncture or flat usually refers to a puncture caused by the wheel hitting a bump that deforms the tire so much the tube is pinched between tire and rim. Frequent pinch flats indicate tire pressure is too low for the surface being ridden on.

Comment: And one characteristic of a pinch flat is that two holes are formed in the tube, one on the outer diameter and another on the inner diameter, just an inch or so away.

Comment: I suspect OP has mixed "Pinching the tube" during installation with "pinch flat" which do sound similar but are not the same.

Comment: You can pinch the tube under the bead (or a tyre lever) reinstalling if you are careless, and the tube is totally flat and airless. I put a couple of pumps of air in so it is a flacid donut  before putting the tyre on. Too much air - can't fit the tyre